# CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url - Anaconda

Tags: python, ssl, anaconda

I have seen other post solving through `ssl_verify` making it false or adding the path of the certificate. I have done every one of them. I have installed and reinstalled several times the anaconda. I have disabled my antivirus program.

I have tried every option that I find online but nothing is working for me and I still get this error.

```
CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64/current_repodata.json>
Elapsed: -

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.

If your current network has https://www.anaconda.com blocked, please file
a support request with your network engineering team.

SSLError(MaxRetryError('HTTPSConnectionPool(host=\'repo.anaconda.com\', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /pkgs/main/win-64/current_repodata.json (Caused by SSLError("Can\'t connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available."))'))
```

I'm not sure what I'm should be doing?

Comment: What environment are you in? Is `base` activated? I had a similar issue on a system that I had little controll over and the admin did some weird stuff with PATH/`conda init` which lead to me getting SSLError when I tried to run a conda command in an activated custom env without having activated base before. I.e. `conda activate my_env -> conda install something` lead to an SSLError whereas `conda activate base -> conda activate my_env -> conda install something` worked perfectly fine. Which I suppose makes some sense, since `conda` is in the base env.

Answer (score 10):

I strongly recommend to copy libcrypto-1_1-x64.* libssl-1_1-x64.* from .\Library in Anaconda folder to .\DLL in Anaconda folder. I'm 100% sure that your problem will be solved. Please don't crack your heads looking for solution on all the platforms.
Don't try editing .condarc file and face further issues. I am sure that problem will be solved after moving the above mentioned DLL files as directed.[image]

Answer (score 3):

I'm getting the same problem in Windows Subsystem for Linux (version 2) with "conda create -name sx python=3.7" the weird thing is "wget [https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64/current_repodata.json"](https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64/current_repodata.json%22) works fine, so I have no idea why conda is failing to fetch this file...

Answer (score 1):

For me the issue gone after changing in c:\Users\user_xxx.condarc:
"ssl_verify: true" to "**ssl_verify: false**"

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue on win 10 and i resolved it by uninstalling the avast antivirus on my PC. I don't know if it's a good idea but i tried it and the issue was resolved.

Comment: Antivirus are often a problem. Be careful and maybe install another.

Answer (score 0):

in linux, `conda config --set ssl_verify no` resolves the issue.