# CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url

Tags: python, conda

Goal: `conda create -n sdg python=3.8.8`

Using:

- miniconda3
- Python 3.8.**10**
- Poetry project Python 3.8.**8**

Command doesn't run in `(base)` venv either.

Bash Terminal:
(`conda install python=3.8.8` also causes the same error)

```
me@PF2DCSXD:/mnt/c/Users/me/Documents/GitHub/foo/bar$ conda create -n sdg python=3.8.8
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): failed

CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64/current_repodata.json>
Elapsed: -

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.

If your current network has https://www.anaconda.com blocked, please file
a support request with your network engineering team.

'https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64'

me@PF2DCSXD:/mnt/c/Users/me/Documents/GitHub/foo/bar$ sudo conda create -n sdg python=3.8.8
[sudo] password for me: 
sudo: conda: command not found
```

`conda list`:

```
# packages in environment at /home/me/miniconda3:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_libgcc_mutex             0.1                        main  
_openmp_mutex             4.5                       1_gnu  
brotlipy                  0.7.0           py39h27cfd23_1003  
ca-certificates           2021.7.5             h06a4308_1  
certifi                   2021.5.30        py39h06a4308_0  
cffi                      1.14.6           py39h400218f_0  
chardet                   4.0.0           py39h06a4308_1003  
conda                     4.10.3           py39h06a4308_0  
conda-package-handling    1.7.3            py39h27cfd23_1  
cryptography              3.4.7            py39hd23ed53_0  
idna                      2.10               pyhd3eb1b0_0  
ld_impl_linux-64          2.35.1               h7274673_9  
libffi                    3.3                  he6710b0_2  
libgcc-ng                 9.3.0               h5101ec6_17  
libgomp                   9.3.0               h5101ec6_17  
libstdcxx-ng              9.3.0               hd4cf53a_17  
ncurses                   6.2                  he6710b0_1  
openssl                   1.1.1k               h27cfd23_0  
pip                       21.1.3           py39h06a4308_0  
pycosat                   0.6.3            py39h27cfd23_0  
pycparser                 2.20                       py_2  
pyopenssl                 20.0.1             pyhd3eb1b0_1  
pysocks                   1.7.1            py39h06a4308_0  
python                    3.9.5                h12debd9_4  
readline                  8.1                  h27cfd23_0  
requests                  2.25.1             pyhd3eb1b0_0  
ruamel_yaml               0.15.100         py39h27cfd23_0  
setuptools                52.0.0           py39h06a4308_0  
six                       1.16.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0  
sqlite                    3.36.0               hc218d9a_0  
tk                        8.6.10               hbc83047_0  
tqdm                      4.61.2             pyhd3eb1b0_1  
tzdata                    2021a                h52ac0ba_0  
urllib3                   1.26.6             pyhd3eb1b0_1  
wheel                     0.36.2             pyhd3eb1b0_0  
xz                        5.2.5                h7b6447c_0  
yaml                      0.2.5                h7b6447c_0  
zlib                      1.2.11               h7b6447c_3
```

`conda info`:

```
     active environment : None
            shell level : 0
       user config file : /home/me/.condarc
 populated config files : 
          conda version : 4.10.3
    conda-build version : not installed
         python version : 3.9.5.final.0
       virtual packages : __linux=4.4.0=0
                          __glibc=2.31=0
                          __unix=0=0
                          __archspec=1=x86_64
       base environment : /home/me/miniconda3  (writable)
      conda av data dir : /home/me/miniconda3/etc/conda
  conda av metadata url : None
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
          package cache : /home/me/miniconda3/pkgs
                          /home/me/.conda/pkgs
       envs directories : /home/me/miniconda3/envs
                          /home/me/.conda/envs
               platform : linux-64
             user-agent : conda/4.10.3 requests/2.25.1 CPython/3.9.5 Linux/4.4.0-19041-Microsoft ubuntu/20.04.3 glibc/2.31
                UID:GID : 1000:1000
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
```

`conda info -a`:

```
     active environment : None
            shell level : 0
       user config file : /home/me/.condarc
 populated config files : 
          conda version : 4.10.3
    conda-build version : not installed
         python version : 3.9.5.final.0
       virtual packages : __linux=4.4.0=0
                          __glibc=2.31=0
                          __unix=0=0
                          __archspec=1=x86_64
       base environment : /home/me/miniconda3  (writable)
      conda av data dir : /home/me/miniconda3/etc/conda
  conda av metadata url : None
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
          package cache : /home/me/miniconda3/pkgs
                          /home/me/.conda/pkgs
       envs directories : /home/me/miniconda3/envs
                          /home/me/.conda/envs
               platform : linux-64
             user-agent : conda/4.10.3 requests/2.25.1 CPython/3.9.5 Linux/4.4.0-19041-Microsoft ubuntu/20.04.3 glibc/2.31
                UID:GID : 1000:1000
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False

# conda environments:
#
base                  *  /home/me/miniconda3

sys.version: 3.9.5 (default, Jun  4 2021, 12:28:51) 
...
sys.prefix: /home/me/miniconda3
sys.executable: /home/me/miniconda3/bin/python
conda location: /home/me/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conda
conda-build: None
conda-env: /home/me/miniconda3/bin/conda-env
user site dirs: ~/.local/lib/python3.8

CIO_TEST: <not set>
CONDA_EXE: /home/me/miniconda3/bin/conda
CONDA_PYTHON_EXE: /home/me/miniconda3/bin/python
CONDA_ROOT: /home/me/miniconda3
CONDA_SHLVL: 0
CURL_CA_BUNDLE: <not set>
PATH: /home/me/miniconda3/bin:/home/me/miniconda3/condabin:/home/me/.vscode-server/bin/d6ee99e4c045a6716e5c653d7da8e9ae6f5a8b03/bin/remote-cli:/home/me/.poetry/bin:/home/me/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/mnt/c/Program Files/Common Files/Oracle/Java/javapath:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/Oracle/Java/javapath:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/system32:/mnt/c/WINDOWS:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/OpenSSH/:/mnt/c/Users/me/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/mnt/c/Users/me/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin:/mnt/c/ProgramData/me/GitHubDesktop/bin:/mnt/c/Users/me/AppData/Local/Programs/Git LFS:/mnt/c/Users/me/AppData/Local/Programs/Git LFS:/mnt/c/Users/me/AppData/Local/Programs/Git/cmd:/snap/bin
REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE: <not set>
SSL_CERT_FILE: <not set>
```

`conda list --show-channel-urls`:

```
# packages in environment at /home/me/miniconda3:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_libgcc_mutex             0.1                        main    defaults
_openmp_mutex             4.5                       1_gnu    defaults
brotlipy                  0.7.0           py39h27cfd23_1003    defaults
ca-certificates           2021.7.5             h06a4308_1    defaults
certifi                   2021.5.30        py39h06a4308_0    defaults
cffi                      1.14.6           py39h400218f_0    defaults
chardet                   4.0.0           py39h06a4308_1003    defaults
conda                     4.10.3           py39h06a4308_0    defaults
conda-package-handling    1.7.3            py39h27cfd23_1    defaults
cryptography              3.4.7            py39hd23ed53_0    defaults
idna                      2.10               pyhd3eb1b0_0    defaults
ld_impl_linux-64          2.35.1               h7274673_9    defaults
libffi                    3.3                  he6710b0_2    defaults
libgcc-ng                 9.3.0               h5101ec6_17    defaults
libgomp                   9.3.0               h5101ec6_17    defaults
libstdcxx-ng              9.3.0               hd4cf53a_17    defaults
ncurses                   6.2                  he6710b0_1    defaults
openssl                   1.1.1k               h27cfd23_0    defaults
pip                       21.1.3           py39h06a4308_0    defaults
pycosat                   0.6.3            py39h27cfd23_0    defaults
pycparser                 2.20                       py_2    defaults
pyopenssl                 20.0.1             pyhd3eb1b0_1    defaults
pysocks                   1.7.1            py39h06a4308_0    defaults
python                    3.9.5                h12debd9_4    defaults
readline                  8.1                  h27cfd23_0    defaults
requests                  2.25.1             pyhd3eb1b0_0    defaults
ruamel_yaml               0.15.100         py39h27cfd23_0    defaults
setuptools                52.0.0           py39h06a4308_0    defaults
six                       1.16.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0    defaults
sqlite                    3.36.0               hc218d9a_0    defaults
tk                        8.6.10               hbc83047_0    defaults
tqdm                      4.61.2             pyhd3eb1b0_1    defaults
tzdata                    2021a                h52ac0ba_0    defaults
urllib3                   1.26.6             pyhd3eb1b0_1    defaults
wheel                     0.36.2             pyhd3eb1b0_0    defaults
xz                        5.2.5                h7b6447c_0    defaults
yaml                      0.2.5                h7b6447c_0    defaults
zlib                      1.2.11               h7b6447c_3    defaults
```

Comment: [Similar post's solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59023267/17840900) detail various solutions/ problems causing `HTTP 000`

Comment: [Git Issue](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/11227) on conda/conda

Comment: [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62483686/17840900). Will update Git Issue :)